# how to loop the url in options in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```html
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=1',//To get all the users data from the repos
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=2',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=3',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=4',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=5',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=6',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=7',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=8',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=9',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=10',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=100&page=11',
  
  'headers': {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json',//to get topics of the repos
    'Authorization': 'Bxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'User-Agent' : 'sxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

In this above code i want to loop the urls continuously until the end of the page
if not anyone have the idea of using pagination in this help me out

Comment: An Object can't have multiple **key** of **same name**. The last key overwrites the others. I think you need to put all url in array

Comment: No because that's not how `request` works. You'll have to run your requests in a loop instead. This will be hard in callback-style though, so I'd suggest using `await` instead.

Comment: @CherryDT could you help me with that loop coding as i am new into this

Comment: If you new to JS and have questions to my answer, please write a comment under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cYou cannot have multiple attributes for one object key. You have to call every url individually. I tried to solve this using asyncronous code, because looping with callback functions is confusing and dangerous with regard to the call stack.

```js
const request = require('request');

// configuration for the url generation
const perPages = 100;
const startPage = 1;
const endPage = 11;
const url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organizationName/repos?per_page=%perPages%&page=%page%';

// define a asyncronous call for one url
async function callOneUrl(url) {
  // local options for each url
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json',
      Authorization: 'Bxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     'User-Agent': 'sxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function (error, response) { 
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
}

// call each url with a for loop
(async () => {
  for (let i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {
    // using the await statement to get the resolved value of the Promise instance or catch the error
    try {
       var response = await callOneUrl(url.replace('%perPages%', perPages).replace('%page%', i));
       // handle response here
       console.log(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
       // handle errors here
       throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download a list of repos with a [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop. We'll set a maximum number of pages to download and exit when we reach either this or the last page.

I would suggest using the [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) package to allow us to use the very nice async-await syntax.

Now, I've given the example of downloading repos for the mongodb org. You can easily replace with whatever one you wish.

I would also note that the request library is now deprecated, we can use it of course, but we must consider replacing in the future.

We now also log the repo information and save it to the output file.

```
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
const fs = require("fs");

async function downloadRepoInformation(org, outputFile) {

    let repoList = [];
    let page = 0;
    const resultsPerPage = 20;
    const maxPages = 10;
    const uri = `https://api.github.com/orgs/${org}/repos`;

    do {
        try {
            let response = await rp.get({ uri, json: true, qs: { per_page: resultsPerPage, page: ++page }, headers: {"User-Agent" : "request"} });
            console.log(`downloadRepoInformation: Downloaded page: ${page}, repos: ${response.length}...`);
            repoList = repoList.concat(response);
            console.log("downloadRepoInformation: response", JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
            console.log("downloadRepoInformation: repoList.length:", repoList.length);
            if (response.length < resultsPerPage) {
                console.log(`downloadRepoInformation: Last page reached: exiting loop...`);
                break;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`downloadRepoInformation: An error occurred:`, error);
            break;
        }
    } while (page <= maxPages)

    console.log("downloadRepoInformation: download complete: repoList.length:", repoList.length)
    console.log("downloadRepoInformation: Saving to file:", outputFile);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, JSON.stringify(repoList, null, 4));
}

downloadRepoInformation("mongodb", "./repolist.json");
```

Comment: it is not giving the data its only showing the page numbers and they are also not complete                                                                             
downloadRepoInformation: Downloaded page: 1, repos: 3...
downloadRepoInformation: repoList.length: 3
downloadRepoInformation: Last page reached: exiting loop...
downloadRepoInformation: download complete: repoList.length: 3

Comment: Hi @Mukesh, thanks for testing the code. I'll update to log the repo information too!

Comment: ok@Terry Lennox if you have any simplified version of code you can share

Answer (score 0):

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.example.com"];
const promises = urls.map(url => request(url));
Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    // data = [promise1,promise2]
});

Apart from above you can also use async.eachseries or async.parallel etc..
```